# subprocess.Popen() and Shell=True results in error 'The syntax of the command is incorrect'

Tags: python, shell, path, windows-xp, command-prompt

I seem to have discovered a problem with `subprocess.Popen()` on a Windows XP x64 machine. If `Popen()` is called with `Shell=True`, instead of a subprocess being created, the error

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

is printed to the command prompt.

The problem was discovered when trying to use Mercurial on the command line. 'hg resolve' would crash with the above error. I've narrowed it down to a problem with Popen(), and have made a <10 line script that reproduces the issue. The problem also exists in tortoisehg in a variety of places, also due to the fact it makes use of `Popen()` with `Shell=True`.

Interestingly, if I run my test-code with Shell=False, it works fine (expected behaviour occurs). I've tested the code on a Windows x86 build, and with both `Shell=True` & `False` it works as expected. This specific machine has some customizations to the PATH, however nothing serious.

Does anybody know what could be different about this x64 machine to cause this error. The machine was already installed/setup before I came into the job, so I am unsure what has been changed. The only idea I've had so far is that there's some error occurring due to incorrect escaping of parameters (or something related), however I'm unsure where this could occur.

Just for informational purposes, I've posted one of Mercurial's calls to `Popen`, in case anybody spots something which might be the issue

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=-1,
                     close_fds=closefds,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     universal_newlines=newlines,
                     env=env)
```

Unfortunately I can't post the test-code right now (it's at work), however I will post an update the moment I can get my hands on it.

---

Update, the code for the test is below...

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if 'THG_HGTK_SPAWN' in os.environ:
    print 'spawn successful'
    sys.exit(0)

os.environ['THG_HGTK_SPAWN'] = '1'

subprocess.Popen(args={'python', r'test.py'}, shell=True)

print 'spawning...'

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: The documentation can be of some help. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html
The shell=True/False is explained only a few lines into it.

Comment: Yeah I understand what Shell= does, I just don't understand why when Shell=True (so the program is going to be executed within cmd.exe), it causes cmd.exe to emit this error. Googling for 'The syntax of the command is incorrect' shows plenty of people who are having trouble with batch scripts, but I can't relate their problems to Popen()

Comment: " *args* should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments"—but you pass a set.

Comment: Agreed that's an error on my part. However, that still does not explain why it works on an x86 machine but not on the x64 machine. Also, Mercurial's code I'm sure will be doing the right thing, and it suffers from the same problem (I'm trying to get Mercurial working on the machine). Thanks for the info though...